# How make a closable p:selectOneButton?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I need to change the `selectOneButton` look to something like a 'x' in upper corner and then with when press click it vanishes.

The `splitButton` was nice try but it doesn't have the boolean behavior (change color when true or false).

Here is my code snippet:

```
<p:selectOneButton id="soLoaders" value="#{bean.id}" styleClass="ui-buttonset-3" >
    <p:ajax  listener="#{bean.deleteThis}" update="cbDelete" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.siLoaders}"/>
</p:selectOneButton>
```

I didn't find any component with this behavior, so i hope somebody could suggest something very close to achieve this.

Comment: Wrap the button in a conditionally-`render`ed container - the outputPanel is a good start - and ajax update the `render` attribute on click

Comment: @kolossus Could you explain in more detail your idea?